# xcode thrown error when logging NSURL

Tags: xcode, nsurl

can anyone help solve this error when running xcode with the following code and trying to nslog url1

.m file

```
        NSLog(@"URL flag is not set, Reverting to stored value");
//url1 = [NSURL URLWithString: [NSString stringWithFormat: @"http://radio.qkradio.com.au:8382/listen.mp3"]];
        url1 = [NSURL URLwithString:@"http://radio.qkradio.com.au:8382/listen.mp3"];
        NSLog(url1);
```

.h file

```
NSURL *url1;
```

error

```
2013-04-14 09:18:41.958 iQkradio[61530:4803] REACHABLE!
2013-04-14 09:18:41.990 iQkradio[61530:c07] Application windows are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch
2013-04-14 09:18:42.569 iQkradio[61530:4803] URL flag is not set, Reverting to stored value
2013-04-14 09:18:42.570 iQkradio[61530:4803] +[NSURL URLwithString:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x1ef926c
2013-04-14 09:18:42.570 iQkradio[61530:4803] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[NSURL URLwithString:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x1ef926c'
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in your code. The correct code is:

```
url1 = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://radio.qkradio.com.au:8382/listen.mp3"];
```

Notice that the "W" is uppercase, as mentioned [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/Reference/Reference.html). Hope this helps!

Comment: I fixed it, but i still have the same issue

Comment: You still get the exact same error after you make this change?

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, you need to use `URLWithString:`.

But there is more.  Try formatting your log like this `NSLog(@"%@",url1);`